# How do I complete this login script?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, registration

I've almost completed my login script, but I don't know how to check if the username & password is correct. 
Here's my script files.

1. index.php:

   ```
   <html>
   <body>

   <form action="action1.php" method="post">
   Username: <input type="text" name="uname">
   Password: <input type="password" name="pword">
   <input type="submit">
   </form>

   </body>
   </html>
   ```

The index.php file is just the page that I use to collect the info from my users for registration.

1. action1.php:

   ```
   <?php
   $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
   if (!$con)
   {
   die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   mysql_select_db("user1", $con);

   $sql="INSERT INTO useri1 (uname, pword)
   VALUES
   ('$_POST[uname]','$_POST[pword]')";

   if (!mysql_query($sql, $con))
   {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   echo "1 record added";

   mysql_close($con);
   ?>
   ```

The action1.php file is just the page that registers the users into the database.

1. login.php:

   ```
   <html>
   <body>

   <form action="checklogin.php" method="post">
   Username: <input type="text" name="uname1">
   Password: <input type="password" name="pword1">
   <input type="submit">
   </form>

   </body>
   </html>
   ```

The login.php file is just the page I use for the users to type their login info in.

Now this is my problem, I have no idea of how to check the users login info so they can proceed to the members only area. I'm a newbie & any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks,

--Devin

Comment: Well, Could anyone at least tell me how to correct this script & make it work instead of leaving me comments about stuff I don't yet understand. I learn better by actually seeing my mistakes corrected!

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you want to use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php) instead of mysql, because mysql is outdated and no longer actively developed. Secondly you want to start escaping your database queries to stop sql injection. In the code below, I used a session to keep track of the user. You can learn more about sessions [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp).

```
<?php

session_start();

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', DB_PASSWORD, 'user1');

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_error)
  die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);

/* escape string from sql injection */
$userName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['uname1']);

/* query database */
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `pword` FROM `user1` WHERE `uname` = '".$userName."'");
if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
  while ($col = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    // This presumes you're storing your passwords in plain text.
    // If you hashed your passwords or anything, you would have to do the same to $_POST['pword']
    if ($_POST['pword'] == $col['pword']) {
      // You could do anything here, but sessions are a way of keeping track of a user.
      $_SESSION['userName'] = $_POST['uname1'];
      $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
    }
  }
}
$result->close();

/* don't forget to close the connection */
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: what is the point of using `real_escape_string` if you can use prepared statements? :)

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski honestly, I've just always used `real_escape_string`, I'm not sure about performance or usage differences.

Comment: @JakeGould His example is great that's why I upvoted his answer and removed mine, still IMO it's easier to use prepared statements than real_escape_string

Answer (score 1):

You would run a query along the lines of this:

```
$user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM useri1 WHERE uname=" . $_POST['uname'] . " AND pword=" . $_POST['pword'] .";";
```

And if the query returns a value, then they can proceed. If the query returns nothing, they cannot pass. As for the logic, look at the code you have created and see how to create `if` and `else` statements to handle the logic.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a SELECT query - something along the lines of

`SELECT STRCMP('{$_POST['pword']}', pword) FROM useri1 WHERE uname = '{$_POST['uname']}'`

This should return a value in the range [-1, 1] - if it is not 0, the password is wrong. If there is no rows, the user does not exist.

You need to think about SQL injections as well - but that could very well be an exercise for another day.

Comment: Whoops - it's fixed now :)

Comment: Thanks - my PHP is a bit rusty, it seems.